# Find time complexity for merge sort in some conditions

Tags: java, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort

Given a changed merge sort algorithm such that if the array is already sorted the algorithm will return the array instead of making 2 more recursive calls.
Assuming we run the new algorithm on an array where each value in it appears exactly n/log(n) times. (And for that the array contains log(n) different values).

What is the time complexity of that algorithm?

Comment: Sounds like you writing down your homework assignment. So, step one: what are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I'll give you a hint.  In O(n) time you can extract just the unique items from the list.  Since you know how many you have of each unique item, you can sort this smaller list, and then in O(n) time construct the actual result by creating a new array with the right number of copies of each item in sorted order.  If you find that your sort has O(n) or higher complexity, which it will, these operations don't change the complexity of the sort. - So the problem is reduced to sorting just the unique items, which there are log(n) of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you suspect the array to have very few different values, scanning the array to extract these values, sort them and count them will take substantially less time than performing a full merge sort on the array:

- If you use a hash table, selecting the values will take **O(N)** time, producing a sample array of size **log(N)**.
- sorting this sample array should take **O(log(N).log(log(N))**, negligible compared to the scan phase.
- enumerating the sample array to generate copies into the original array also has linear time complexity **O(N)**.

Hence the time complexity could be reduced to **O(N)**.

Note however that:

- using a hash table might not be feasible to construct the sample array. If instead you construct a sorted list, the complexity jumps back to **O(N.log(N))** because of the linear lookup into the sample array for each element.
- generating copies of the elements might not be adequate if the original array's elements have identical keys but different contents. In this case, you would scan the original array and lookup the element's key in the sample array to determine where to store the element in the resulting array, again **O(N.log(N))** time complexity if the sample array is a list, and **O(N.log(log(N)))** if it is an array and you use binary search.

As a conclusion, the complexity can be reduced efficiently in special cases, but it is tricky in the general case.